# How to make countifs and sumifs operate as "OR" instead of "AND"

Tags: excel, formula, countif, sumifs

I am trying to make a formula that uses SUMIFS and COUNTIFS to find an average of numbers with one of two criteria from different columns. So I want it to add the numbers in one column if the criteria is met in either range 1 or range 2 or both, not if its met only for both. And I need to do the same for the COUNTIFS.

Right now I have it formatted as

```
=SUM(SUMIF(XX:XX,"<130"ZZ:ZZ),SUMIF(YY:YY,"<80",ZZ:ZZ))/SUM(COUNTIF(XX:XX,"<130"ZZ:ZZ),COUNTIF(YY:YY,"<80",ZZ:ZZ))
```

But I know it is adding some numbers twice since it goes down both columns and counts the ones that have both, twice.

This is my attempt in using COUNTIF to work as COUNTIFS as an OR operator instead of AND, does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: So why not use AVERAGEIFS() ?

Comment: Sum both sumifs like sumifs criteria1 + sumifs criteria2

Answer (score 0):

You can do it combining 2 SUMPRODUCTS, 1 to get the sum of all values that met criteria, and a second one to count how many values met criteria, and then do the average.

[image]

In this case I want to get the average of values in column A only if column B or C equals to 1. The green values are the only ones that meet this requirement, a total of 8 values.

If we do `(3+4+5+7+8+9+11+12)` we get 59, and `59/8=7.375`, the result of my formula

My formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((B1:B15<2)+(C1:C15<2))<>0);A1:A15)/SUMPRODUCT(--(((B1:B15<2)+(C1:C15<2))<>0))
```

The first SUMPRODUCT will return the sum value:

`SUMPRODUCT(--(((B1:B15<2)+(C1:C15<2))<>0);A1:A15)`

This is how it works:

1. `(B1:B15<2)` will return an array or False/True if value is <2. In this case we get `{0;0;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;0}`
2. `(C1:C15<2)` same than before, but in column C, so we get `{0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0}`
3. `--(((B1:B15<2)+(C1:C15<2))<>0)` The double unary operator will check if the sum of both previous arrays are distinct to 0 (that means that ROW is valid), returning 1 if true, 0 if false. so it returns `{0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;0;0;0}`
4. We multiply array from step 3 with values in column A and we sum them up, obtaining 59

The second SUMPRODUCT works exactly the same, but there isn't step 4, so we get just a sum of 1 and 0 to get how many values meet criteria, in this case 8.

And finally `59/8=7.375`